# Dynamically change JFrame Properties at runtime in Java

Tags: java, jframe

I need to runtime change `JFrame` properties in below code but i got error. `F_3x3` is a `JFrame`. Please help me:

```
public class WinnerClass {
        public void RunEnd(short who){
            System.out.format("Player %d wins",who );
> *F_3x3.setVisible(false);*
        }
        public boolean win3x3( short who){
            if (((mat9[0]==who)&&(mat9[1]==who)&&(mat9[2]==who))||
                ((mat9[0]==who)&&(mat9[4]==who)&&(mat9[8]==who)))
                    return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

```
 i need something like this:

F_3x3.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: You shouldn't refer to that frame there. The frame's visibility should be controlled by the code that *calls* that `Winner` class (not `WinnerClass` - string "Class" is completely redundant). [Method names](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) start lower case in Java btw

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "WinnerClass" is a name that i choose. imagine i change it to "looooooser".

Comment: You could, but it probably wouldn't work any better

Comment: I don't think it happens because of name. Names can't make difference. It's about code.